# How can i persist objects in multiple persistence contexts transaction-wise?

Tags: java, jpa, jta

i'm working with 2 different databases (DB2 & SQLSERVER). I've got two persistence units defined in my persistence.xml. I have an stateless ejb in which i inject both persistence contexts.

I have a method that needs to read certain records from database A, write some data there and if everything's ok write something to database B. I'm getting this exception:

> *com.ibm.ws.Transaction.IllegalResourceIn2PCTransactionException: Illegal attempt to enlist multiple 1PC XAResources*

I'm pretty sure i cannot do it the way i'm trying to but i don't know what strategy i should use instead. Different persistenceContext in different ejbs? I'm pretty lost here, any ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need a Transaction Manager like Atomikos to manage transactions between 2 different database sources. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073281/object-is-not-saved-in-mysql-schema-by-hibernate-4-jpa-2-0-jta-using-atomikos) shows you how to configure it using JPA, Hibernate and Spring, but I'm sure you can adapt it to your environment.